# How to properly reference the Strings.xml file, android

Tags: android, string

My string.xml has a string:

```
<string name="loginLocation">http://website.com/afile.php</string>
```

In my java file, I am trying to reference it like so:

```
url = new URL(R.string.loginLocation);
```

except I am getting the error:

```
The constructor URL(int) is undefined
```

I managed to get the error to go away by doing:

```
url = new URL(Integer.toString(R.string.loginLocation));
```

except when I make the call to it, I get a Protocol Error

I can do:

```
url = new URL("http://website.com/afile.php");
```

and it works fine, but I'd like to define it in the Strings.xml file. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to do it in a method of the `Activity` subclass, then do the following:

```
url = new URL(getString(R.string.loginLocation));
```

Answer (score 0):

[getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) will give you a lot of methods for accessing what's in your /res directory. Among the rest, the method you are looking for is `getString(R.string....)`, which is also available directly from your `Context` (without the `Resources` object).

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

this.getxt(R.string.btn_menu_logout);

What nobody mentions online is to put .this before gettxt() or getText():