# getting info from string.xml in android studio does not work

Tags: java, android, xml

I have written this line in **mainActivity.java**:

```
String url = getString(R.string.url2);
```

and ind **strings.xml** it looks like this:

```
<string name="url2">https://someurl.com/index.html</string>
```

but I get an error and if I write it like this in mainActivity.java

```
String url = "https://someurl.com/index.html";
```

then it works fine, but I need it to be in strings.xml for it to be easy to change.

How do I make it work?

**EDIT**: I have tried these:

```
String url = this.getString(R.string.url2);
String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url2);
```

and they do not work. The error I is that it does not get the url, simply said **R.string.url2** does not lead to my url in strings.

Update: I have found the error, I had written it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String url = this.getString(R.string.url2);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

but I should have written it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        url = this.getString(R.string.url2);
```

Thank you to those of you who tried to help with my problem.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Use logging to debug what is coming from your strings file and what you are sending to network.
I would suggest you clean your project and double check your code. Strings.xml is tried and tested by millions of people.

Comment: Instead of having your url in strings.xml file move it to a class as a static string variable and access it through the class

Comment: using url in a string is fine as long as you don't use &.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your code should work if it is not working then please try like this

**Trick 1**

```
String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url2);
```

**Trick 2**

```
this.getString(R.string.url2)
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

xml code `<string name="kms">KMs:</string>`

You can get the string by using this

```
String name=getResources().getString(R.string.kms);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do it in a method of the `Activity` subclass, then do the following:

```
url = new URL(getString(R.string.url2));
```

Or you can try using [getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29)

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/5888219/4758255

Another related link for using url in string:

1. [URL in String resource xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341487/url-in-string-resource-xml)
2. [How to properly reference the Strings.xml file, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888151/how-to-properly-reference-the-strings-xml-file-android)
3. [Android: How store url in string.xml resource file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237462/android-how-store-url-in-string-xml-resource-file)
4. [How to put the url on string.xml in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836638/how-to-put-the-url-on-string-xml-in-android)

Comment: witch imports do I need do make url = new URL(getString(R.string.url2)); work?

Comment: try `import java.net.URL;`